# my project is virtual piano I need when user click keyboard key the piano button get hover color

Tags: javascript

I'm working on javascript piano app, I need when user click on key 83 the piano button hover but after the user releases the key the button get back to its original color

I tried to add the style. background = 'green'; but it changes the button color forever

```
var a = document.getElementById("mydo"); /* div 'piano button' */

if(key===83){
    DO();
     a.style.background = 'gold'; /* This Wrong Change color forver */
}
```

I need something like hover when I use the mouse to click the button which means the color change while I hold the key and back transparent again after I finish

Comment: Please show all your relevant code, what event are you using?

Comment: haha your name.. anyways dont use click, use mousedown/mouseup

Comment: Do not forget to mark one of the answer as accepted with the green checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to change the background-color of your item

```js
const keys = document.getElementsByClassName("key");

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const key = keys.item(i);
  key.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "gold";
  });
  key.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "ghostwhite";
  });
}
```

```css
.key {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="do" class="key">do</div>
<div id="re" class="key">re</div>
<div id="mi" class="key">mi</div>
<div id="fa" class="key">fa</div>
<div id="sol" class="key">sol</div>
<div id="la" class="key">la</div>
<div id="si" class="key">si</div>
```

Comment: Consider to make the mouseup on everything (body) and make all of the buttons gray again. Now you can press on one, drag away and it stays yellow.

Comment: @Veda Thanks for the proposition ! Indeed my solution is now working fine when dragging your mouse out of the div but it is a starting point for OP

Answer (score 1):

Use event keydown and key up to set desired values of the styling.

```
var a = document.getElementById("mydo");

document.onkeydown = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 83){
    a.style.background = 'gold'
  };
};

document.onkeyup = function(event){
  if(event.keyCode === 83){
  a.style.background = 'transparent'}; /* the starting color  */
  }
```